# (Excel) Reporting Street Numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Does anyone know if it's possible to generate a report for missing address street numbers in Excel?

For example, we have three records of addresses in Apple St (no.5, 9, 11), is it possible to generate a report that will:

List all the *recorded* street numbers per street in the workbook, and

Also generate a list of street numbers missing per street, using 1 as a min variable and the largest recorded street number as the max variable in range?

```
       **Sample Data**
Street Number:   Street Name:
5                Apple St.
9                Apple St.
11               Apple St.
6                Lemon Rd.
3                Watermelon Cl.
```

So from this sample data, ideally I would like to generate a report like:

```
Street Name:    Recorded Street Numbers:
Apple St.       5, 9, 11
Lemon Rd.       6
Watermelon Cl.  3

Street Name:    Missing Street Numbers:
Apple St.       1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10 
Lemon Rd.       1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Watermelon Cl.  1, 2
```

I've used INDEX and MATCH to make a distinct list of Street Names, but as to how to list the Street Numbers as a string of multiple variables has stumped me.

I starting to think I may need to use VBA to get what I want, but also I need to keep this as simple as possible so the people that use this report can update and modify it.

Any help or pointer into the right direction would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2013 at the office, and I have Excel 2016 at home, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you:

```
Sub Check_Street_Number()
Dim i As Long, iStreet As Long, Street As String, Cel As Range

ActiveSheet.Name = "Inputs"
If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count = 1 Then Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("Inputs")
Sheets(2).Name = "Output"

Sheets("Inputs").Activate
Range("B2").Select
Range("B2:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
Sheets("Output").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
Range("A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 3).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2).Value = "Street Name:"
Range("B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2).Value = "Missing Street Numbers:"
Range("A1").Value = "Street Name:"
Range("B1").Value = "Recorded Street Numbers:"
Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
Range("A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2 & ":B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2).Font.Bold = True

Do Until iStreet = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Cells.Count
    i = 1
    iStreet = iStreet + 1
    Street = Cells(1 + iStreet, 1).Value
    Do Until i > WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Inputs").Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row))
        Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(Inputs!R[1]C[-3]:R[5]C[-3],""" & Street & """,Inputs!R[1]C[-4]:R[5]C[-4]," & i & ")"
        If Range("E1").Value = 0 Then
            If Range("B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2 + iStreet).Value = "" Then
                Range("B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2 + iStreet).Value = i
                Else
                    Range("B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2 + iStreet).Value = Range("B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2 + iStreet).Value & ", " & i
            End If
            Else
                If Range("B" & 1 + iStreet).Value = "" Then
                    Range("B" & 1 + iStreet).Value = i
                    Else
                        Range("B" & 1 + iStreet).Value = Range("B" & 1 + iStreet).Value & ", " & i
                End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Range("B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 2 + iStreet).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Range("B" & 1 + iStreet).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
Loop

Range("E1").Value = ""
Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give me best answer @garc